# Get text patters from string using regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

In C# .NET
I have a string with 
`PSL44T-VK5VF-2B` 
`PSL-44TVK5-VF2B` 
`PS-L44-TVK-5VF-2B` 

using regular expression can I get the result format as 
`XXXXXX-XXXX-XX <-  PSL44T-VK5VF-2B` 
`PSL-XXXXXX-XXXX <- PSL-44TVK5-VF2B` 
`XX-XXX-XXX-XXX-2B <- PS-L44-TVK-5VF-2B`  
`XX-L44-XXX-XXX-XX <- PS-L44-TVK-5VF-2B`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. But if you want to filter a list of strings with regular expressions, you can do as follows:

```
List<string> inputs = new List<string>();
inputs.Add("PSL44T-VK5VF-2B");
inputs.Add("PSL-44TVK5-VF2B");
inputs.Add("PS-L44-TVK-5VF-2B");

var myRegex = new Regex("^PSL-.{6}-.{4}$"); // for PSL-XXXXXX-XXXX

List<string> resultList = inputs.Where(f => myRegex.IsMatch(f)).ToList();
```

and result:

[image]